# How to uninstall foxit reader from Ubuntu 20.04 using terminal?

Tags: 20.04, foxitreader

I installed foxit reader following this [link](https://idroot.us/install-foxit-reader-ubuntu-20-04/) But the font is too small. I'm not able to uninstall it using the uninstaller. I'm using UBuntu 20.04 and very new to Ubuntu. Can it be done on terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and run `rm -r ~/opt/foxitsoftware/ ~/.local/share/applications/FoxitReader.desktop` and you should be good to go!

You can also open your file manager, press `Ctrl+H` on your keyboard *(to show hidden folders in the file manager)*, open the `opt` folder in your home directory, delete the folder `foxitsoftware` inside, go back to your home directory and open the folders *(in order)* `.local -> share -> applications` and delete the file `FoxitReader.desktop`.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps **to correctly uninstall Foxit Reader** from Ubuntu (tested on 20.04)

1. Check the installation directory from .desktop

```bsh
tail -2 ~/Desktop/FoxitReader.desktop
```

2. Go to the installation directory (mine is the following)

```bsh
cd ~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/
```

3. The uninstall script is *Uninstall.desktop*, but this is just a shortcut for another (the really one) file *maintenancetool.sh* so **execute it and Follow the graphical instructions**

```bsh
./maintenancetool.sh
```

[enter image description here][Uninstallation Screenshot]

4. Cleanup stales files

```bsh
rm -vrf ~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/ 
rm -vrf ~/.local/share/Foxit*
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proprietary application that uses its own custom installer. The application therefore is installed independently from the APT package management system, so the latter does not know about it.

Where the application is installed, entirely depends on the choices of the Foxit developers. Typically, it might be installed under the /opt directory, which is conventionally used for custom installed applications outside of the management of your distribution.

Perhaps the software provides an uninstall script or application. Otherwise, you only may be able to manually remove the installed files if you know where they are. Note also that the application probably also installed a `.desktop` launcher. That may be placed in `/usr/share/applications`. Otherwise, you may locate it with `find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Search String" {} \; 2>/dev/null`, where you could replace "Search String" by the name displayed in the application overview.